# Sum up values in case of a subquery returning multiple rows. (my use case is 2 rows)

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have multiple rows coming through a query. How can I group up these rows to sum up the value of some of the rows and leave the rest.

```
set total_fees1 = (select (f.total_Fees2) from fee_Collection f where f.student_Id =minstudent_Id);
            set total_fees2 = (select (f.total_Fees3) from fee_Collection f where f.student_Id =minstudent_Id);
            set paid_amount1 = (select (f.paid_amount2) from fee_Collection f where f.student_Id =minstudent_Id);
            set paid_amount2 = (select (f.paid_amount3) from fee_Collection f where f.student_Id =minstudent_Id);
```

These above query returns 2 rows for some cases. Now I have to add the paid_amount value in the cases I am getting more than 1 row and take the first rows value of total_fees field.

Comment: you should probably share table structure, sample data, expected output, what have you done so far, what is the result that you got, and what should it be

Answer (score 0):

That would be:

```
set total_fees1 = (select (f.total_Fees2) from fee_Collection f where f.student_Id =minstudent_Id LIMIT 1);
        set total_fees2 = (select (f.total_Fees3) from fee_Collection f where f.student_Id =minstudent_Id LIMIT 1);
        set paid_amount1 = (select SUM(f.paid_amount2) from fee_Collection f where f.student_Id =minstudent_Id);
        set paid_amount2 = (select SUM(f.paid_amount3) from fee_Collection f where f.student_Id =minstudent_Id);
```